# LXC container on proxmox points to incorrect domain

Tags: dns, cloudflare, lxc, proxmox

I created an LXC container that contains a Wordpress instance with Proxmox. This was a development version of a website.

While in development, I had a subdomain setup on my own site [dev1.mysite.com]. I set this up on cloudflare. This worked just fine.

However, I want to put the website in production now. I asked the client (who manages his own DNS) to point an A record to the IP address of the LXC.

I removed the record on cloudflare that pointed towards [dev1.mysite.com]. I also changed hostname in the dns setting of the lxc settings of the container in proxmox.

But the IP address still points towards my original [dev.mysite.com]. I can't figure out why, is there any additional step that I should undertake?